# Lateral shake on div hover(CSS3 only)

Tags: html, css

Still embarking on my css3 adventure! Basically I'm trying to shake a div left and right on hover subtly. I believe i have most of the markup and styles correct but it's just not firing. Would love some insight into this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Code as follows.

```
<div class="brief-boxes">
        <div class="details-box">
            <div class="stats">
                <p class="number">1</p>
                <p class="stat-title">title</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details-box">
            <div class="stats">
                <p class="number">2</p>
                <p class="stat-title">title</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details-box">
            <div class="stats">
                <p class="number">3</p>
                <p class="stat-title">title</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

.brief-boxes {width:100%;}
    .brief-boxes .details-box {color:#fff; float:left; width:32.7%;padding:10px; margin-top:15px;/*min-height:100px;*/ background-color:yellow;}
    .brief-boxes:after {clear:both;display:block;content:'';}
    .brief-boxes .details-box .stats .number {font-size:40px;}
    .brief-boxes .details-box .stats .stat-title {}
```

CSS3 animations:

```
.details-box:hover {
  animation: shake .5s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  20% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  40% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }

  60% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Again thank you for your time.

Comment: Works well on firefox & IE 11(even if the yellow is killing eyes) : http://jsfiddle.net/xkepsdLn/ Are you sure your browser is CSS3 compatible ? http://css3test.com/

Comment: Sorry about the yellow took out my business logic and added dummy markup/styles. Using Chrome so may need mark the below answer as marked. Thanks for your comment. Shall take a look at the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you viewing your code in a webkit browser like Chrome? You need to make sure you include the appropriate browser prefixes:

```css
.brief-boxes {width:100%;}
    .brief-boxes .details-box {color:#fff; float:left; width:32.7%;padding:10px; margin-top:15px;/*min-height:100px;*/ background-color:yellow;}
    .brief-boxes:after {clear:both;display:block;content:'';}
    .brief-boxes .details-box .stats .number {font-size:40px;}
    .brief-boxes .details-box .stats .stat-title {}

.details-box:hover {
  -webkit-animation: shake .5s ease-in-out;
  animation: shake .5s ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  20% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  40% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }

  60% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  80% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="brief-boxes">
        <div class="details-box">
            <div class="stats">
                <p class="number">1</p>
                <p class="stat-title">title</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details-box">
            <div class="stats">
                <p class="number">2</p>
                <p class="stat-title">title</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="details-box">
            <div class="stats">
                <p class="number">3</p>
                <p class="stat-title">title</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation) is a great resource for determining if you need to include browser prefixes.

Comment: I cant believe i missed that. To be honest i just assumed it would work. But never the less great answer and i'll be sure to check the link. Code works like a dream with the prefixes. I almost had it haha Thank you.